# Is it possible to create classes in NetLogo?

Tags: class, netlogo

I searched this on the internet, but could not find any answer. I want to create classes in NetLogo, but as far as it seems, the only way to do so is to create an extension using Java.

Is is possible to define and use classes in NetLogo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breeds are the closest thing NetLogo has to 'classes' as implemented by most object-oriented languages.

```
breed [agents agent]
```

NetLogo does not fix methods to objects. Once you define a method in Netlogo:

```
to doit []
....
end
```

then you can 'invoke' this method on any breed (think, 'object') by doing

```
ask agents [doit]
```

But you could also

```
breed [puppies puppy]
ask puppies [doit]
```

Kinda like [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin).